# Lightbox Login Form stopped working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, lightbox

The Register & Login links on my website are placed on a lightbox JS script on the homepage. It used to work pretty well till sometime back, but suddenly I realized that the links are not working at all. I don't remember having fiddled with the code any time in the recent past.

I am not a developer myself, but when I checked the code on Firebug console as suggested on a related thread here, I did not find any missing JS file or paranthesis or anything similar. Could someone please help me out on this? Here is the page in question : http://bridgeurl.com

Answer (score 1):

```
            "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://bridgeurl.com/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"

            jquery....min.js

            TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function
            [Break On This Error]   

            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

            bridgeurl.com (line 46)

            TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function
            [Break On This Error]   

            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
```

I am getting all the error above from bridgeurl.com.Check all the files carefully.
You Jquery inclusion path was wrong. Correct that one and all the JS include files path.

YOu can include google hosted jquery in your HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
```